# Having difficulty understanding what happens when reversing order of quaternion multiplication.

Tags: linear-algebra, quaternions

The textbook I am reading claims that quaternion multiplication works like so:

$
q_1q_2 = V_1 \times V_2 + s_1V_2+s_2V_1+s_1s_2-V_1 \cdot V_2
$

Which is a simplified view of

$
q_1q_2 = (x_1w_2+y_1z_2-z_1y_2+w_1x_2)i\\
+(y_1w_2+z_1x_2+w_1y_2-x_1z_2)j\\
+(z_1w_2+w_1z_2+x_1y_2-y_1x_2)k\\
+(w_1w_2-x_1x_2-y_1y_2-z_1z_2)
$

where $q$ is defined as:

$q=xi+yj+zk+w$

Which makes sense to me if you take into consideration the multiplication rule for quaternions:

$i^2=j^2=k^2=ijk=-1$

The thing that I don't understand is how reversing the order of quaternion multiplication works. The textbook defines it as:

$q_2q_1=q_1q_2-2(V_1 \times V_2)$

However I have no idea how to go about obtaining this result.

Comment: Just a quick remark: you can't *define* the multiplication in the reverse order. Once you defined multiplication, you can of course apply that definition in any order you want. What you can do is *prove* that some formula is true when you reverse the order.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So we start with the "definition" of multiplication:
$$
q_1q_2 = V_1 \times V_2 + s_1V_2+s_2V_1+s_1s_2-V_1 \cdot V_2
$$
and then ask ourselves, what would be $q_2 q_1$, instead? Well, we simply need to swap the indices:

$$\
\begin{split}
q_2q_1 &= V_2 \times V_1 + s_2V_1+s_1V_2+s_2s_1-V_2 \cdot V_1\\
&= V_2 \times V_1 + s_2V_1+s_1V_2+s_1s_2-V_1 \cdot V_2\\
\end{split}
$$
The last two terms were switched because both scalar multiplication and dot product are commutative. Now you can easily subtract $q_2q_1 - q_1q_2$ to get the result
$$
\begin{split}
q_2 q_1 - q_1 q_2 &= V_2 \times V_1 - V_1 \times V_2\\
&= -V_1 \times V_2 - V_1 \times V_2\\
&= -2V_1 \times V_2\\
\end{split}
$$

Answer (score 12):

In $q_1q_2 = V_1 \times V_2 + s_1V_2+s_2V_1+s_1s_2-V_1 \cdot V_2$ the $s_1V_2+s_2V_1+s_1s_2-V_1 \cdot V_2$ part is symmetrical in $1,2$. Hence won't change when you permute the $q_1q_2$ product.

The only part that changes is $V_1 \times V_2$ which is [anticommutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anticommutativity), i.e. $V_2 \times V_1 = -V_1 \times V_2$.

This explains the result $q_2q_1=q_1q_2-2(V_1 \times V_2)$.